# Do we really need that "system" tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging

There are currently [five questions tagged](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system) [system](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system), but I am not sure that it really adds anything. How do others see it?

Comment: I have retagged all five of those questions.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me that most of the things currently tagged with system fall under "Core language" questions. With the symbol tag, I agree that system doesn't really add anything.  Core-language might be a better classification and more meaningful than symbol however.

Answer (score 2):

If we can come up with a better tag, I'm all for it.  I originally created [system](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system) to cover low-level sorts of questions.  Contexts and symbol naming, the kernel parser, evaluator, assignment etc...

Andy's [core-langauge] is one possibility, although that implies syntax to me for some reason.

How about [core-kernel]?

(I'm also not sure whether we need [symbol](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/symbol).  For the most part I think we're shying away from individual functions, although I expect there will be exceptions for things like `Manipulate` and `NDSolve`.)

Comment: I agree that [tag:symbol] isn't that useful. But we should have [tag:symbolic] as the antonym to [tag:numeric]

Answer (score 2):

I have a third alternative: [system-core](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system-core). It doesn't imply syntax, and highlights that we mean the core components of mma.

Comment: +1 - this is a good suggestion. Unfortunately not all things people would tag as system should be tagged as system-core.